# What are some ideas for code that can be used for getting items for a text based game in Pycharm?

Tags: pycharm

This is the code I have written so far for a text-based prison break game. The goal of the game is to escape from Alcatraz by collecting various items and adding them to your inventory.

```py
rooms = {
    "Laundry Room": {"South": "Roof", "East": "Common Area", "West": "Security Office"},
    "Common Area": {"West": "Laundry Room", "North": "Warden's Office"},
    "Warden's Office": {"South": "Common Area"},
    "Rec Room": {"South": "Laundry Room", "East": "Cell"},
    "Cell": {"West": "Rec Room"},
    "Security Office": ("Exit",),
    "Roof": {"North": "Laundry Room", "East": "Dock"},
    "Dock": {"Exit": "Exit"}
}

print("Welcome to Alcatraz!")
print("Collect 6 items to win the game, or possibly be caught by the Warden.")
print("Move commands: go South, go North, go East, go West")
print("Add to Inventory: get 'item name'")
print("-----------------------------------")
print("Welcome to the Prison Break Game")
print("The Prison Break Game 2023")
print("****************************")
print("Directions:")
print("Find your way through the various cells and collect items to assist you in your journey! :)")
print("To navigate the cells, type:")
print("North\nEast\nSouth\nWest")
print("****************************")
print("BEGIN")
print("****************************")

current_room = "Cell"

while current_room != "Exit":
    print("You are in your", current_room)
    print("Which direction will you decide to go?")
    direction: str = input("> ").title()

    if direction in rooms[current_room]:
        current_room = rooms[current_room][direction]
    else:
        print("Unfortunately, you can't go that way.\nYou have been caught by the Warden. GAME OVER, Try again!(:")

print("you found a way out\n you made it out...for now")

# function to display player status
def player_status(inventory, current_room, rooms):
    print('\nInventory:', inventory)
    print('You are in', current_room)
    
    if 'item' in rooms[current_room]:
        print('You see a', rooms[current_room]['item'])
    
    print("-----------------------------------")

# main game function
def main():
    # inventory to hold items
    inventory = []
    
    # game play loop
    while True:
        # calling player status function
        player_status(inventory, current_room, rooms)

        # getting user command
        command = input('Enter Command\n')

        # game movements
        if command.split()[0] == 'go':
            command = command.split()[1].capitalize()
            
            if command in rooms[current_room]:
                current_room = rooms[current_room][command]

        # branching to pick up items
        elif command.split()[0] == 'get':
            command = command.split()[1].capitalize()
            item = rooms[current_room].get('item', '').capitalize()

            if command == item:
                inventory.append(command)
                del rooms[current_room]['item']
            else:
                print("I don't see that here")

        # overall input validation
        else:
            print('Invalid Command')

# calling main function to run program
main()
```

I am able to move across rooms but I am unable to access my inventory or find items in the rooms. If I encounter the villain, the game does not end as expected, so I have to restart the entire game. I need help with adding the inventory and Items to the various rooms and gathering items while trying to escape the prison. Thank you for any help!(: